# WSO2 IS can confirmation codes be set to stay valid for multiple attempts

Tags: wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 IS 5.0.0 and are implementing the user recovery process. We have noticed that when the user gets the confirmationCode from the email sent from executing the soap call "sendRecoveryNotification" in UserInformationRecoveryService that the confirmationCode is only valid for one attempt.

Is there a way to set the confirmationCode to remain valid until the user successfully updates their password as well as other similar operations requiring WSO2 generated confirmationCodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed with [1] and will be available in IS 5.1.0-Alpha-2

Isura

[1]https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-3175